# Create publication is not working in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, replication, backup

I am trying to create a publication (for logical replication) in PostgreSQL database but it throws an error:

```
indsolv_dev=# CREATE PUBLICATION my_publication;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PUBLICATION"
LINE 1: CREATE PUBLICATION my_publication;
```

Comment: What version are you using (`select version();`)?  CREATE PUBLICATION was not implemented until v10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [JJanes](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/34857/jjanes) mentioned, Publication is available from Version 10.
I was using version 9.6.